# Add "include" directories from multiple folders

Tags: cmake

On Windows, I install dependencies to `c:\sdk\my_dependency\`, where each dependency folder contains `include`, `lib`, `bin` etc...

Within a `CMakeLists.txt` for a project, how can I add every sub-`include` folder within `c:\sdk` to my list of include directories? (And similarly for `lib` to my list of link library directories)

i.e. is it possible to specify `c:\sdk\**\include` in my `CMakeLists.txt`?

And is this advisable practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the typical CMake idiom is to use `find_package()` for finding and populating CMake variables (`*_INCLUDE_DIRS`, `*_LIBRARIES`) for third-party packages, what you're suggesting can also be achieved using the [`GLOB`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob) subcommand of `file()`. You can use `*` in the globbing expression to grab all of the `include` or `lib` directories in `C:/sdk`:

```
# Make a list of all the include directories.
file(GLOB MY_INCLUDE_DIRS
    C:/sdk/*/include
)

# Make a list of all the lib directories.
file(GLOB MY_LIB_DIRS
    C:/sdk/*/lib
)
```

The `GLOB` option is powerful, and has a recursive capability for more complex situations, so I encourage you to check out the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob).